# Data Studio Community Connector for Bigquery - advanced-services

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am customizing an advanced service community connector. In this case to keep it simple I omit the parameters and do a query.

I follow the following example:
[Advanced Services de Data Studio](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/advanced-services?hl=es-419)

I checked the getData () method for better documentation:
[A JavaScript object representing the BigQuery query configuration.](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference?hl=es#getdata)

I checked the Data Studio advanced service example repository for the most complete example:
[getData(request)](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-samples/blob/master/data-studio/caas.gs)

Manifest : `"useQueryConfig": true`

The code is as follows (a simple query):

```
<code>var sqlString = ' SELECT name FROM `xxxx-101010.xxxx.xxxxxx` ';
function getAuthType() {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  return cc.newAuthTypeResponse()
      .setAuthType(cc.AuthType.NONE)
      .build();
}
function getConfig(request) {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  var config = cc.getConfig();
  return config.build();
}
function getFields(request) {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  var fields = cc.getFields();
  var types = cc.FieldType;
    fields.newDimension()
    .setId('newDimensionName')
    .setName('Package')
    .setType(types.TEXT);
    return fields;
}
function getSchema(request) {
  return {schema: getFields().build()};
}
function getData(request) {
  var authToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var bqConfig = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector().newBigQueryConfig()
      .setAccessToken(authToken)
      .setUseStandardSql(true)
      .setQuery(sqlString)
      .build();
  return bqConfig
}
</code>
```

The query I have tried with a table created by me (Permission: BigQuery data owner) and a public table (Permissions by default).

[Error (Data Studio)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgWvq.png)

Comment: I included the BigQuery service in the manifest by adding it as a Service in the left panel. Then `BigQuery.Jobs.query` can be used without further auth.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm facing a similar issue. Thanks

Comment: I am very frustrated that no further detailed Error is returned. facing the same issue.

Comment: The error can be due to several reasons. Be sure to review each step. Job credentials. Script properties > SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS and oauth2.example service. Libraries > OAuth2. Service > BigQuery. code :` //aggregations fields.newMetric().setId('Record_Count') .setName('Record_Count').setFormula('COUNT($id)') .setType(types.NUMBER).setAggregation(aggregations.AUTO); `  `var BASE_SQL = 'SELECT * FROM `EXAMPLE.EXAMPLE.TABLE` '; `. Also, the data types of the table and the fields in the code. I went through each step to solve it and it worked.